# PowerShell Zip Not Working on Windows 7

Tags: powershell

I'm running the following PowerShell script successfully on Windows 8.1 and Windows 10:

```
Add-type -A System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
[IO.Compression.Zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory('C:\Test\WiresharkCapture','C:\Test\WiresharkCapture.zip')
```

However when I run this script on Windows 7 I get an error that the System.IO.Compression.FileSystem assembly could not be located.

Could someone advise what I need to do make this assembly accessible to PowerShell on Windows 7?

Comment: PowerShell 2.0 (default in Win7) runs on .NET 2.0 - `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` is available only in .NET 4.5 (and requires at least a 4.0 runtime). Install a newer version of `WMF`/`PowerShell` and it should work

Comment: I had .NET 4.5.1 installed - the correct solution was to upgrade PowerShell as suggested by @MathiasR.Jessen, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

It's not about Powershell itself. It's more about .NET version installed.

It was included since version of .NET framework 4.5.

So you will not be available to run it with lower version of .NET.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx

You have to check your .NET Framework version.

Based on the MSDN article, you could add a switch to return the marketing product version number for releases after 4.5:

```
Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -recurse |
Get-ItemProperty -name Version,Release -EA 0 |
Where { $_.PSChildName -match '^(?!S)\p{L}'} |
Select PSChildName, Version, Release, @{
  name="Product"
  expression={
      switch($_.Release) {
        378389 { [Version]"4.5" }
        378675 { [Version]"4.5.1" }
        378758 { [Version]"4.5.1" }
        379893 { [Version]"4.5.2" }
        393295 { [Version]"4.6" }
        393297 { [Version]"4.6" }
        394254 { [Version]"4.6.1" }
        394271 { [Version]"4.6.1" }
        394747 { [Version]"4.6.2" }
        394748 { [Version]"4.6.2" }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is kind of right, but not really the way right, while I do like your code sample :) .  In reality the ZIP features were added in PowerShell v5.0 (delivered as WMF 5.0).  It happens that WMF 5.0 DOES require dotnet 4.5.  But simply installing dotnet 4.5 won't allow OP to use the Archive Cmdlets.

Comment: The original question was about loading an assambly that doesn't have required methods due to, most likely, .NET installed lower than v4.5